# How to read local xml file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

Maybe the problem is that i wrote path to my file incorrectly, i'm using Linux, do i have to write path in some different way?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function func(){
    var xmlFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlFile.open("GET", "/home/kat/course/data.xml", false);
    xmlFile.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlFile.responseXML;

    document.getElementById("result_field").value = xmlDoc;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using a local server? (As in, `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`?)

Comment: Could you show us the error message?

Comment: @Tresdin there's no error message, it just doesn't add info from data.xml to the html element with id="result_field"

Comment: What do you have in `xmlDoc`?

Comment: @Tresdin in xmlDoc i have (i hope so) info from my data.xml document, which is: 
     <a>something</a>

Comment: @KaterynaHurenko Then make sure this tag `result_field` is an input or a textarea. Otherwise you won't see the result.

Comment: You will need to use a file input to manually select the file and the file api to read a local file if it is not available to the web server. Where is the webserver running from? `/kat`?

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be in the webroot.
So if you have the code in /var/www and your site is 'somedomain.com/index.html' you will need to have the xml file in the same /var/www directory and access it like "GET", "somedomain.com/anotherfolder/data.xml"...
You can't access server directories from JS... The javascript runs on the client side, not on the server side, so the file needs to be accessible on the website.

Comment: thank you for the answer. and if i'm using a local server? what my path must look like?

Comment: The path can also be relative, the only thing is that the file will need to be accessible on the web server... so if you have index.html in a folder, put the data.xml in the same folder, and do the get to "/data.xml". Keep in mind that it will not work if you don't have the index.html file opened as HTTP ( for example if you open it like "C:\something\index.html" )

Answer (score 0):

There could be two problems. The url must be `{your_server_domain}/home/kat/course/data.xml`, and the `document.getElementById("result_field")` must be an input/textarea to accept value attribution, otherwise, use `innerHTML`.

P.s.: Your local server domain usually is: `localhost` or `127.0.0.1:80`.

Comment: In an `XMLHttpRequest`, the URL actually can be relative to the file calling it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can only access files your server is serving. Unless you are serving `/home/kat/course/data.xml`, you're going to need to move `data.xml` before your JavaScript can access it. Once you move it to a location being served, it will be accessible via an XHR.

As a side note, the `responseXML` property of an XHR is a `Document` object, not a string. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML